# Change row values in Redshift/ SQL Server database

Tags: sql, sql-server, rename, amazon-redshift, alter

I know we can rename output values using logical functions in our queries. But does anyone know how to permanently rename/change values within redshift and sql server databases?

Comment: Sample data and desired results would clarify what you really want to do.

Comment: Are you asking for Redshift or Microsoft SQL Server? What do you mean by "rename/change values"?

Comment: Can you change data within rows in the sql server and redshift database. For example if some rows of data within a state column were misspelled, is there a way to permanently change them to a correct spelling in these systems?

Answer (score 0):

Somehow, I'm assuming that you mean column names.

In SQL Server, you would simply use [`sp_rename`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-rename-transact-sql):

```
exec sp_rename 'table_name.old_name', 'new_name', 'COLUMN';
```

In Redshift, you use [`alter table`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_ALTER_TABLE.html#r_ALTER_TABLE-synopsis):

```
alter table table_name rename column old_name to new_name;
```